# city not found Yahoo weather api

Tags: api, yahoo, city

I am using yahoo weather api to pull weather data for a certain location. I am getting error that says "city not found".

The location is "Islamabad, Pakistan" with WOEID=2211027

Here is the xml request uri, i am using:
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2211027&u=c&d=7.xml

It was working few days back. But now it shows error saying city not found, Any ideas?

Thanks Awais

Comment: Choose another city close by?

Comment: i tried 'Rawalpindi' and 'Wah' these are near by cities, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the coordinates?
If yes, you can try metwit [weather API](http://metwit.com/weather-api/).

Here is a working and simple jQuery example : http://jsbin.com/isukam/1

Disclosure: I own this sweet API. Let know if you need help.